# Android studio Sqllite Data type date Select between date1 And date2

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, simpledateformat

Hello member Stackoverflow . 
I'm newer programer android ..My App used Sqllite 
I have table Like that :

```
Id   name   Date
1    jon    2017-01-09
2    jon    2017-02-03
3    jon    2017-03-10
```

I stored Date in table type(text ) 
in Activity I have edit_start_date & edit_End_date 
I want to

```
"select date Between edit_start_date AND  edit_end_date "
```

how I do that ....

Comment: Hello, unclear what you're asking

Comment: @Andremoniy edited the Question

Comment: @juergend in Sqllite not have column date type 
it just 
text . bol ,int ,real 
no Date !

Comment: `select * from your_table where date(date) Between date(edit_start_date) AND  date(edit_end_date)`

Comment: @juergend
what you mean in date ? 
columon name ?

Comment: It seems you have a column named `Date`, but `date` is also a function.

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano
i try that it's not work :( 
can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you case, using `Date` (the column) alphabetical order would work, so

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN edit_start_date AND edit_end_date;
```

is the query you are looking for (of course you have to replace the variables (which I guess they are) by their values.

Use `sqlite3` from the command line to experiment with the DB and test queries.